# Parameter 'DeltaToken' not supported for this request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Microsoft Graph API (beta version), the following error occurs periodically when receiving teams messages:

> Status Code: BadRequest.
> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest
> Message: Parameter 'DeltaToken' not supported for this request.,
> this error occurs for request GET `/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/delta`.

Usually everything works, but sometimes this error occurs.
The application token is used for access.

This request in the code:

```
var request = GraphServiceClient.Teams[teamId]
        .Channels[channelId]
        .Messages
        .Delta()
        .Request();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: like, what is the request you're making?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue. See it on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7382). If there is no specific feature you are using in beta, I suggest you try v1.0 and see if you get the same issue